# Spring Security login for 2FA - First check username and password, and then ask for 2FA code if required

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

I have set 2FA up with spring security. The problem is, at the moment the 2FA code must be entered in the same form as the username/password. Is there a way to ask for the username and password first, and then, if they are valid, ask for the 2FA code?

Answer (score 2):

I have done the same in angularJs. 
The logic: 
When the user has 2FA enabled, on form submit with only username and password, instead of returning a bad credentials response (401) or a success response, I return a Status code (403) indicating the server understood the request but refused to fulfill it.

When angular receives this 403 status it hides the username and password field and shows the OTP field. At this point the username and password are still present as angular objects but only hidden.

When the user enters the OTP and clicks submit, I again make a post call and this time pass the username, password and OTP.

Comment: Did you create your own endpoint for verifying username/password manually at the first form submit with user name and password? And then at step two actually calls the loginProcessingUrl provided By Spring Security?

Comment: If you use the same loginProcessingUrl for step 1, and the Authentication is stored in the SecurityContext already at step 1, is there any issue with the AbstractRememberMeServices?